# How to restore dangling tf.py_func within the tf.data.Dataset() with tf.saved_model API?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-datasets

After doing a research for restoring the `tf.py_func()` when using saved_model API in vain, I couldn't find other information than documented in [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func):

> The operation must run in the same address space as the Python program that calls `tf.py_func()`. If you are using distributed TensorFlow, you must run a `tf.train.Server` in the same process as the program that calls `tf.py_func()` and you must pin the created operation to a device in that server (e.g. using with `tf.device()`:)

Two save/load snippets help to illustrate the situation.

**Save part:**

```
def wrapper(x, y):
    with tf.name_scope('wrapper'):
        return tf.py_func(Copy, [x, y], [tf.float32, tf.float32])

def Copy(x, y):
    return x, y

x_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None], 'x_ph')
y_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None], 'y_ph')

with tf.name_scope('input'):
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_ph, y_ph))
    ds = ds.map(wrapper)
    ds = ds.batch(1)
    it = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(ds.output_types, ds.output_shapes)
    it_init_op = it.make_initializer(ds, name='it_init_op')

x_it, y_it = it.get_next()

# Simple operation
with tf.name_scope('add'):
    res = tf.add(x_it, y_it)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), it_init_op], feed_dict={y_ph: [10] * 10, x_ph: [i for i in range(10)]})
    sess.run([res])
    tf.saved_model.simple_save(sess, './dummy/test', {'x_ph': x_ph, 'y_ph': y_ph}, {'res': res})
```

**Load part:**

```
graph = tf.Graph()
graph.as_default()
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], './dummy/test')

    res = graph.get_tensor_by_name('add/Add:0')
    it_init_op = graph.get_operation_by_name('input/it_init_op')
    x_ph = graph.get_tensor_by_name('x_ph:0')
    y_ph = graph.get_tensor_by_name('y_ph:0')
    sess.run([it_init_op], feed_dict={x_ph: [5] * 5, y_ph: [i for i in range(5)]})

    for _ in range(5):
        sess.run([res])
```

**Error:**

> ValueError: callback pyfunc_0 is not found

It's well known that the function wrapped by the `tf.py_func()` isn't saved with the model. Does anybody has a solution to restore this by using the small hint given by the tf doc applying `tf.train.Server`

Comment: It seems there's no solution with Tensorflow since when we save the model the pythonic part isn't saved with. To pass around this problem, one should prune the `py_func()` in the input pipeline while doing `import_meta_graph()` and pass/cut the input gate node with argument `input_map='input_pipeline/IteratorGetNext':new_inputpipeline_with_pyfunc` Still waiting for another better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as no answer, I will suggest mine, which contour the pb instead of solving it. Struggling for a long time, I finally neglected it by pruning it. Then graft the new input/ouput to it with a simpler way the placeholder. Moreover, this **py_func is deprecated in TF2.0**.